# OpenGL 4.x textures not working

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I'm new here.
I'm having trouble with textures in OpenGL 4.4, I just get a black screen.
Here's my code (I suspect everything before glGenBuffers() is unimportant but you never know):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "eternity.h"
#include "error.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STBI_FAILURE_USERMSG
#include "stb_image.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        DIE("%s\n", "not enough arguments");

    GLuint width = 0, height = 0, bpp = 0;
    unsigned char *image_raw;

    if ((image_raw = stbi_load("image.jpg", &width, &height, &bpp, 0)) == NULL)
        DIE("stbi error: %s\n", stbi_failure_reason());

    uint8_t rv;
    if (rv = initialize_glfw())
        DIE("%s%" PRIu8 "\n", "initialize_glfw() failed with code ", rv);

    glfwSetErrorCallback(glfw_error_callback);

    glfw *glfw = malloc(sizeof(glfw));
    if (!(glfw->window = glfwCreateWindow(
                    width,
                    height,
                    "Eternity",
                    NULL,
                    NULL)))
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        DIE("%s\n", "glfwCreateWindow failed");
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(glfw->window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(glfw->window, glfw_key_callback);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        eternity_cleanup(glfw);
        DIE("%s\n", "glewInit() failed");
    }

    printf("OpenGL %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    GLshort vertices[] = {
        -1,  1, 0,
         1,  1, 0,
        -1, -1, 0,
         1, -1, 0
    };

    GLushort texcoords[] = {
         0,  0,
         1,  0,
         0,  1,
         1,  1
    };

    gl gl = {0}; // This is just a struct

    glGenBuffers(1, &(gl.points_vbo));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.points_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * sizeof(GLshort), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &(gl.texcoords_vbo));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.texcoords_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * sizeof(GLushort), texcoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.points_vbo); // EDIT: I added this line
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &(gl.vao));
    glBindVertexArray(gl.vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    setup_shaders(&gl);

    GLenum format;
    switch (bpp * 8)
    {
        case 24:
            format = GL_RGB;
            break;

        case 32:
            format = GL_RGBA;
            break;
    }

    GLuint texture_id = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (GLint)format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_raw);
    stbi_image_free(image_raw);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

    check_error();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(glfw->window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(gl.shader_program);
        glBindVertexArray(gl.vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        glfwSwapBuffers(glfw->window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture_id);
    eternity_cleanup(glfw);
}

void setup_shaders(gl *gl)
{
    const GLchar *vs_source =
        "#version 440\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec3 vp;"
        "layout(location = 1) in vec2 vt;"
        "out vec2 texcoord;"
        "void main() { gl_Position = vec4(vp, 1.0);"
        "texcoord = vt; }",
               *fs_source =
        "#version 440\n"
        "out vec4 frag_color;"
        "in vec2 texcoord;"
        "uniform sampler2D texture;"
        "void main() { frag_color = texture2D(texture, texcoord); }";

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vs_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fs_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);
    gl->shader_program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(gl->shader_program, fs);
    glAttachShader(gl->shader_program, vs);
    glLinkProgram(gl->shader_program);
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);
}

uint8_t initialize_glfw(void)
{
    int major = 0, minor = 0, rev = 0;

    glfwGetVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
    printf("GLFW %d.%d rev %d\n", major, minor, rev);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, major);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, minor);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_REVISION, rev);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 8);

    if (!glfwInit())
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

void glfw_error_callback(int error, const char *description)
{
    printf("glfw error callback triggered\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", error, description);
}

void glfw_key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

void eternity_cleanup(glfw* glfw)
{
    glfwDestroyWindow(glfw->window);
    free(glfw);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

I'm not sure if I've forgotten to do something here or if I'm doing something incorrectly, I have tried very hard to fix this but the black screen persists.
I feel like the problem is in my shaders (hardcoded in setup_shaders()), or maybe around glTexImage2D()?

edit:
I found that if I call glBindBuffer again right before glGenVertexArrays, then I get a light blue screen, and the specific image that I am loading is predominantly this exact shade of blue, so I believe I am sampling a single pixel.
I have updated the source code with a comment where I added a line.
My problem is now that I am sampling only one pixel.

Comment: Did you try `frag_color = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);`?

Comment: Ah, great idea.
Just tried it and no, still black.

Comment: Did you check for errors after compilation and linking phase?

Comment: @Varaquilex No, I had forgotten about that but I will do it now, thanks.

Comment: Not the only problem if nothing is rendering at all, but you have the wrong VBO bound when making the second `glVertexAttribPointer()` call (for the texture coordinates), and the second argument should be 2 instead of 3.

Comment: re: `initialize_glfw()`: Why are you trying to request a GL version that matches the GLFW version?  That is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I never request a GL version in that function, unless glfwGetVersion actually gives the GL version and not the GLFW version.

@RetoKoradi Thank you, that actually did the trick, it displays the image correctly now.
But yes I probably have much more "humble" problems in my code.